# Add Disclosure panel in flex table

Tags: java, gwt, flextable

I created new flex table and added disclosure panel with in flex table.
but it showing only disclosure panel.

```
FlexTable flexTable = new FlexTable(); 
flexTable.setCellSpacing(5); 
flexTable.setWidget(0, 0, w1); 

flexTable.setWidget(0, 1, w2);

DisclosurePanel panel = new DisclosurePanel();
panel.setHeader(new Button("TEST"));
panel.setContent(new HTML("TEST"));

flexTable.setWidget(0, 2, panel);
```

Any thing wrong in this code?

Answer (score 0):

Check out your return statement. You are returning `panel`. I think you should return `flexTable` if you are attaching it to any other panel.

Comment: No, here i just wrote for sample, My flextable and disclosure panel are in different classes.

Answer (score 0):

It works fine:

```
package com.example.client;

import com.google.gwt.core.client.EntryPoint;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Button;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.DisclosurePanel;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.FlexTable;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.HTML;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.RootPanel;

public class SO1 implements EntryPoint
{
    public void onModuleLoad()
    {   

        FlexTable flexTable = new FlexTable(); 
        flexTable.setCellSpacing(5); 
        flexTable.setWidget(0, 0, new Button("ok")); 

        flexTable.setWidget(0, 1, new Button("ok2"));

        DisclosurePanel panel = new DisclosurePanel();
        panel.setHeader(new Button("TEST"));
        panel.setContent(new HTML("TEST"));

        flexTable.setWidget(0, 2, panel); 

        RootPanel.get().add(flexTable);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ya. But if you set like this,
w1.setHeight("250px");
w2.setHeight("300px");

w3.setHeight("400px");
disclosurePanel.setContent(w3);
means Disclosure panel design is not properly aligned.
I want to build some more components within w1 & w2.
can you try this.